# php - substr function issue

Tags: php, substr

When we use substr to display part of the string but if our string has anchor tag then displayed string content viewing smaller than others strings

e.g.

```
$str1="is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It";

$str2="is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy <a href='http://www.google.com'>text</a> ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It";

$str1Count=strlen($str1); // 357

$str2Count=strlen($str2); // 393

if($str1Count > 300){
   echo substr($str1,0,300)."<br/><br/>";
}

/* 
output:
is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into el
*/


if($str2Count > 300){
    echo substr($str2,0,300);
}

/* 
output:
is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy <a href='http://www.google.com'>text</a> ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five 
*/
```

but as per my need it has to display till "into el"

please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: seriously, these were the *shortest* string examples you could come up with? :/ how about truncating to 20 characters?

Comment: have you tried `echo htmlspecialchars(substr($str2,0,300));` (asuming you are displaying the result in a browser)?

Comment: htmlspecialchars() not working it displays till "only five"

Answer (score 2):

you may need to use [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
echo substr(strip_tags($str2),0,300);
```

*Note:* Don't forget to use `strip_tags` when checking the length of the string also.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick but it will remove your hyperlink. do you want to keep hyperlink intact?

```
<?php   

$str1="is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It";

$str2="is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy <a href='http://www.google.com'>text</a> ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It";

$str1Count=strlen(strip_tags($str1)); // 357

$str2Count=strlen(strip_tags($str2)); // 393

if($str1Count > 300){
   echo substr(strip_tags($str1),0,300)."<br/><br/>";
}

/* 
output:
is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into el
*/


if($str2Count > 300){
    echo substr(strip_tags($str2),0,300);
}

/* 
output:
is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy <a href='http://www.google.com'>text</a> ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five 
*/

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
function limit_words($string, $word_limit){
    $words = explode(" ",$string);
    return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
}
```

Comment: why use this ?? OP don't want to split words.

Comment: @bansi this will give the proper result and (string has anchor tag then displayed string content viewing smaller than others strings) problem not occur